# Adapting Sutto's RocketPants REST api with Ember.js

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-data, rocketpants

Ember.js expects a json response to contain the model object in the
root of the json. RocketPants encodes it's models on an attribute
called response with the objects as it's value. Also the metadata returned
from RocketPants is in the root next to the response object while 
Ember expects all metadata to reside in an object named meta. As a result
any of the metadata returned by RocketPants will be parsed as an object
and an error will occur in Ember. It will also try to parse the response
object as a response model.

So currently I am trying to decide whether to change the json sent back
from the backend or writing an adapter on the ember side. Writing an 
adapter is the ideal approach but I don't know how easy it is to
accomplish this and am currently researching it.

If I do decide to change the backend I want to keep RocketPants for it's error handling
and just send back my custom json but then the same problem may arise because the json returned uses an error object and Ember might try to parse that as an object unless it takes into account the status code and it understands it's an error.

Does anyone have any incite on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the root key has only one type of records in it you can use the JSONSerializer and overwrite `normalizePayload` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L190) to move the records from the `response` key to the top level.

You can override `extractMeta` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L947) to move the metadata to the `meta` key and call `this._super(store, type, payload)` or to just extract the metadata yourself.

Comment: The problem is that Ember expects the json to be named. For example user or users would need to take the place of response, pluralized depending on the returned json. So without writing an adapter this wouldn't work. I decided I didnt need Rocketpants and after looking over and trying rails-api and active model serializer, I think it is a better suited for use with ember and it is more flexible in general. The training wheels need to come off. Thanks for the help!